# Managing USB Host registration\unregistration

Tags: android, usb, device, host

Im working on two distinct Android applications.

Application1: reads data from an USB NFC Reader
Application2: writes data to the USB NFC Reader

I can manage all the read and write stuff as well as the registration\opening of the USB NFC Reader\Write.
The problem is when I switch between these two applications.

I put the request for permission and the registerReceiver in the onStart() method of both the application.

```
protected void onStart() {
    mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
            Config.ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
    filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Config.ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    for (UsbDevice device : mManager.getDeviceList().values()) {
        if (Config.mReader.isSupported(device)) {
            mManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);

        }
    }
    super.onStart();
}
```

And the unregisterReceiver in the onStop() method of both application:

```
protected void onStop() {
    if (mReceiver != null) {
        try {
            Config.mReader.close();
            unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Utils.log("error");
        }
    }
    super.onStop();
}
```

If I perform this actions:

1. close Application1 by clicking the Home button or the back button and
2. open Application2

everything works fine.

If I use the show application stack button
it looks like Application1 cannot perform the onStop() method before the onStart() method of Application2, resulting in either Application1 nor Application1 having control of the USB Reader.

Am I doing it completely wrong?

Comment: Why do you need two applications?

Comment: @ThomasRS in order to understand how to properly manage USB Host registration\unregistration

Answer (score 0):

To unser my own question, I did this way:

1. I put the registration process in the onStart() method
2. and the unregistration process in the onPause() method

I tried to put the registration in the onPause() method but in this way, when the user is prompted to confirm permission, the prompt window shows 2 times (witch is the normal behaviour accordingly to the Activity lifecycle) and the registration is performed twice.

In the way I did, the registration and the permission process are performed once and the unregistration (in the onPause() method) is performed just in time before the registration of the other app.

Hope this can help.